# Is a public class with getters only an Immutable class?

Tags: java, immutability

Is the following class immutable? If not, why?

How can I change the fields?

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public Student(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does immutable mean?

Comment: This is not the problem -- the problem is that it is not thread safe. And immutable classes are supposed to be thread safe. More specifically, you don't ensure safe publication. If your instance member fields are `final` however, then you will ensure thread safe publication

Comment: What do you think?  Why do you think that?

Comment: @fge What makes you say the class is not thread safe? It seems fine to me.

Comment: @fge: How is this not thread safe?  Two different threads cannot both call the constructor, and I do not believe the object is available to another thread before it is fully constructed.

Comment: @andersschuller instance fields are not `final` -- as such there is no guarantee that they will be effectively set when you `.get()`. The window is small but it is there

Comment: @EricJ. JCIP disagrees with you, and I tend to trust JCIP ;)

Comment: @fge: Strange.  I have not done much with Java for years, but it seems... flawed... that an object could be available for access before it is fully constructed.

Comment: @EricJ. a `final` field gives you the guarantee that initializing such a field _happens-before_ any read of that field; which non `final` field don't guarantee. The JVM can perform reordering if it sees fit.

Comment: instance variables are initialised on creation of object. so, it least string will be null before get is called. why the comparison with final? Instance and final variables are totally different variables all together

Comment: fge is absolutely correct. Without final, volatile or synchronized, the Java memory model makes no guarantee the latest state will be visible by other threads.

Comment: Funny, how a simple question like this can turn out to be such a rich debate.

Answer (score 3):

@fge answer might be more complete. But I don't know of immutable having to be thread-safe. For me they are different properties, even though linking them makes sense.

Nevertheless, for the mutability aspect of being immutable, yes, your class is.

Indeed, I don't know if the concept exists, but I would say that your class is "deeply immutable" : not only you can't change the references of its attributes (which I would call `shallow immutability`), but you can't change the values of its attributes neither as they are themselves immutable.

----UPDATE

I am wrong.

I read the definition given in [Effective Java](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=effective+java+immutable&source=bl&ots=yYLmKiw1M-&sig=d6ogvfT4_sHjet2DkNu-IbzZk1A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fFVIU7emHIay0QXopYGoDA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20immutable&f=false) by Joshua Bloch, and the following is missing (mentionned by others) :

- the class should be final, or have final methods to prevent subclasses to make instances appears like the state has changed.
- all fields should be final to get proper thread-safety

So a correct answer is :

```
public final class Student {

    private final String name;
    private final String age;

    public Student(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not immutable as it could be subclassed (neither the class nor getters are final). A subclass could override the getters and exposing state that could change. Another class holding a reference to `Student` has no assurance that its state can't change, since there could be mutable subclass.

Unrelated is that the fields are not final or volatile. Thus there's no guarantee that another thread will see the latest value.

Comment: I really wonder if this has to see with Immutability or not. A subclass could violate the contract proposed by the class, but still, can't change the values of the attributes of the Student class.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's not immutable unless you do the following:

- make the class `final`, otherwise I could write a subclass that changes the behavior of your class, i.e., make it "behave" like a mutable class *or* make all the getters final *or* make the constructor private and provide a static factory method, so that it can't effectively be subclassed;
- make the fields `final`, so they are thread safe.

As a reference see [this page](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29) or go take a look at [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).

Comment: Technically what you are saying is that a class A is not immutable because there is some class B that happens to extend A and happens to be mutable.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. If I was a malicious client, I could replace instances of A with instances of B and break the immutability so this is not an academic distinction. Note that this is one of Bloch's points about immutable classes.

Comment: If you were really a malicious client then you could even manipulate the byte code itself. Basically, what I am saying is that the question is whether **the** class itself is immutable or not. At least that's what I think it is.

Comment: Let's say I am not a malicious client, just a reckless programmer. So there is your safety hole. Again, this is pretty common practice for immutable classes.

Comment: Agree with @GiovanniBotta, it's less a matter of security, and more a matter of being able to forget about a certain kind of problem. You can think "I don't need to worry about the possibility of a mutable subclass, because it cannot be extended" and move on.

Comment: I would suggest that it's not necessary for a class to be final *if* the base class contract specifies that two instances of any legitimate derived class which report themselves as equal must forevermore be equivalent [note that this goes beyond forbidding derived classes from modifying base-class fields].  Such a contract wouldn't prevent malicious code from writing illegitimate derived classes that behave like mutable objects, but so what?  OOP is reliant upon derived class' obedience to base class contracts in ways that go far beyond immutability.

Comment: I guess one way to enforce that is by having final getters and a sensible implementation of equals. This is actually already very complex (if not more complex) when the classes are mutable since you have to decide whether or not comparing across the hierarchy makes sense (subclass to superclass or viceversa). Bloch discusses that. Martin Odersky goes even further in his [Scala book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Comprehensive-Step---Step/dp/0981531644/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397672932&sr=8-1&keywords=martin+odersky).

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the open source tool [Mutability Detector](http://www.mutabilitydetector.org/) has to say about your `Student` class:
(Disclaimer: I'm the author)

Result:

```
Expected: org.mutabilitydetector.stackoverflow.Student to be IMMUTABLE
 but: org.mutabilitydetector.stackoverflow.Student is actually NOT_IMMUTABLE
Reasons:
    Can be subclassed, therefore parameters declared to be this type could be mutable subclasses at runtime. [Class: org.mutabilitydetector.stackoverflow.Student]
    Field is not final, if shared across threads the Java Memory Model will not guarantee it is initialised before it is read. [Field: name, Class: org.mutabilitydetector.stackoverflow.Student]
    Field is not final, if shared across threads the Java Memory Model will not guarantee it is initialised before it is read. [Field: age, Class: org.mutabilitydetector.stackoverflow.Student]
```

Let's look at the two types of reasons, to explain what they mean:

- **"Can be subclassed..."** This means that *consumers* of your object, for example other classes or libraries that, for example, accept it as a parameter, cannot trust that the instance is immutable, because at runtime, the object can be a mutable subclass. This can be fixed by making the class `final`, or by by not providing a public constructor. If you do not export your class to other users, and you can guarantee there are no subclasses in your codebase, this problem goes away.
- **"Field is not final..."** Although the fields cannot have their reference changed, there is the possibility that users of this object may observe it changing. Due to the semantics of the Java Memory Model, you have to ensure that the object is safely published, otherwise it may look like a field has not had it's reference set in one call, then have it set on subsequent calls. The easiest way to fix this is to mark the fields as `final`, although there are other ways to achieve the same effect. If you only ever run in a single-threaded execution, this problem goes away.

See the test case that produces the result, using Mutability Detector, [here](https://github.com/MutabilityDetector/ClientOfMutabilityDetector/blob/9d6cc39d4c28ed50c1c1a4234fa1cd20dcc68ed2/src/test/java/org/mutabilitydetector/stackoverflow/Question_23021354.java).

While this answer gives the same result as Snicolas, I think it's worthwhile showing you an automated tool that can answer the same question.